# How can I get Dialyzer to accept a call to a function that intentionally throws?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I have a function that intentionally throws when its first argument is the atom `throw`.

A simplified version of this code is:

```erl
-module(sample).

-export([main/1, throw_or_ok/1]).

main(_Args) ->
    throw_or_ok(throw).


throw_or_ok(Action) ->
    case Action of
        throw -> throw("throwing");
        ok -> ok
    end.
```

Dialyzer errors on the call to `throw_or_ok`:

```
sample.erl:7: The call sample:throw_or_ok
         ('throw') will never return since it differs in the 1st argument from the success typing arguments:
         ('ok')
```

Adding specs doesn't help, the error message is the same:

```erl
-module(sample).

-export([main/1, throw_or_ok/1]).

-spec main(_) -> no_return().
main(_Args) ->
    throw_or_ok(throw).

-spec throw_or_ok(throw) -> no_return(); (ok) -> ok.
throw_or_ok(Action) ->
    case Action of
        throw -> throw("throwing");
        ok -> ok
    end.
```

How can I get Dialyzer to accept calls to `throw_or_ok/1` that are guaranteed to throw?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no clean way to mark this as acceptable for Dialyzer via specs.

Perhaps you can use an ignore warning annotation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if will put `throw` it will never return, if will put `ok` the pattern will never match with `throw`. See topic with similar [issue](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-February/064649.html). The logic of `main/1` need to change, eg:

```erlang
main(Args) ->
    MaybeOk = case Args of
        0 -> throw;
        _ -> ok
    end,
    throw_or_ok(MaybeOk).
```

OR

```erlang
main(_Args) ->
    throw_or_ok(_Args).
```